# change the VirtualHost file with php

Tags: php, apache2, debian

I have installed apache on Debian server, and setup some example sites but I would like to make a billing system and automatically update the Virtualhost details like ServerAdmin, ServerName, ServerAlias when order is completed. 
My question is: Is it possible to update them with PHP?

Example site in the sites-available directory:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerAdmin info@example.org
ServerName example.org
ServerAlias www.example.org
DocumentRoot /srv/www/example.org/public_html/
ErrorLog /srv/www/example.org/logs/error.log
CustomLog /srv/www/example.org/logs/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I would create a special group|user(s) that could write to sites-available directory, so the normal user php runs under can't do it. Some|same user|group then has to restart apache for settings to be effective, another security concern to think about. I just wouldn't have anything root|admin related being controlled by the user php runs under. that is asking for trouble I reckon

Comment: how do software like plesk, ensim, and others alter system files like httpd.conf, named.conf, sites-available ...?

And about restarting apache I think the reload command is enough

Answer (score 0):

With the proper write permissions, you can certainly do it. It does seem like you will want some seriously paranoid validation and testing before you restart apache after a write a new one because a malformed directive in there is a quick way to 500.

Edit: I'm not sure I would recommend giving your script the 'proper' write permissions in the first place.

Comment: What is the easiest way, how do other web hosting companies deal with this? when user order a web hosting package then new folder is created for him or already made folder updates it domain details and served to him

Comment: I think people use cpanel for stuff like that. If I am not mistaken they have scripts for it

Comment: Yeah I am familiar with cpanel etc. but I dont have enough money to buy their licenses :/